# Basic 3D Unity Game Singleton throws NullReferenceException only in Build

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, singleton

the basic 2D Jump&Run game I'm currently developing is based on the this code.
https://github.com/angelotadres/RunAndJump

Atm it throws me an NullReferenceException when I run the build.
Here is the complete Debug Message:

```
NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
at RunAndJump.LevelMetadata.get_SceneName () [0x0000c] in 
D:\Dropbox\Dropbox\Unity\RunAndJump-master\Assets\Scripts\Level\LevelMetadata.cs:19 
at RunAndJump.LevelHandlerScene+<InitScene>c__Iterator1.MoveNext () [0x0006c] in D:\Dropbox\Dropbox\Unity\RunAndJump-master\Assets\Scenes\LevelHandler\LevelHandlerScene.cs:85 
at UnityEngine.SetupCoroutine.InvokeMoveNext (IEnumerator enumerator, IntPtr returnValueAddress) [0x00028] in C:\buildslave\unity\build\Runtime\Export\Coroutines.cs:17 
UnityEngine.MonoBehaviour:StartCoroutine_Auto_Internal(IEnumerator)
UnityEngine.MonoBehaviour:StartCoroutine(IEnumerator) (at C:\buildslave\unity\build\artifacts\generated\common\runtime\MonoBehaviourBindings.gen.cs:62)
RunAndJump.<InitSequence>c__Iterator0:MoveNext() (at D:\Dropbox\Dropbox\Unity\RunAndJump-master\Assets\Scenes\LevelHandler\LevelHandlerScene.cs:77)
UnityEngine.SetupCoroutine:InvokeMoveNext(IEnumerator, IntPtr) (at C:\buildslave\unity\build\Runtime\Export\Coroutines.cs:17)
UnityEngine.MonoBehaviour:StartCoroutine_Auto_Internal(IEnumerator)
UnityEngine.MonoBehaviour:StartCoroutine(IEnumerator) (at C:\buildslave\unity\build\artifacts\generated\common\runtime\MonoBehaviourBindings.gen.cs:62)
RunAndJump.LevelHandlerScene:Start() (at D:\Dropbox\Dropbox\Unity\RunAndJump-master\Assets\Scenes\LevelHandler\LevelHandlerScene.cs:58)
```

Here is the problematioc Singleton Class:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;



public class Session : Singleton<Session>  {

    private LevelsPackage _levels;
    private int _currentLevelId = 0;

    private void Awake() {
        _levels = Resources.Load<LevelsPackage>(LevelsPackage.ResourcePath);
        Debug.Log(_levels);
    }

    public void PlayLevel(int id) {
        _currentLevelId = id;
    }

    public void PlayNext() {
        _currentLevelId++;
    }

    public LevelMetadata GetLevelMetadata() {
        return _levels.metadataList[_currentLevelId -1];
    }

    public bool HasNext() {
        return (_currentLevelId < _levels.metadataList.Count);
    }

    public int GetLevelId() {
        return _currentLevelId;
    }

    public int GetTotalLevels() {
        return _levels.metadataList.Count;
    }
}
```

Any ideas why this only happens in the build?
Thanks!

P.S. The LevelMetadata class:

This is the file:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System;

namespace RunAndJump {
[Serializable]
public class LevelMetadata {

    public UnityEngine.Object scene;
    [SerializeField]
    private string levelName;

    public string LevelName {
        get { return (levelName == null || levelName == "") ? "Untitled" : levelName; }
        set { levelName = value; }
    }

    public string SceneName {
        get {
            Debug.Log ("Scene Name : " + scene.name);
            return scene.name;
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: How do you know its this class that's problematic? Have you actually debugged this? *D:\Dropbox\Dropbox\Unity\RunAndJump-master\Assets\Scripts\Level\LevelMetadata.cs:19* is where the error is. *hint:* `RunAndJump.LevelMetadata.get_SceneName`

Comment: I copied the code in my question.

Answer (score 0):

> NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
>   at RunAndJump.LevelMetadata.get_SceneName () [0x0000c] in 
>   D:\Dropbox\Dropbox\Unity\RunAndJump-master\Assets\Scripts\Level\LevelMetadata.cs:19

Read the error carefully: It says the error is on line 19 of `LevelMetadat.cs` and it happens when calling `get_SceneName()` method. Now you do do not have a `get_SceneName` method but properties under the hood are created as methods. Therefore, the `get_SceneName` method is the getter in the property named `SceneName`. So the issue is in the code below:

```
public string SceneName {
    get {
        Debug.Log ("Scene Name : " + scene.name);
        return scene.name;
    }
}
```

In that code, the only items which can possibly be null is `scene`. So you need to debug your code and figure out why `scene` is null. If `scene` is allowed to be null then you need to do something about it like this:

```
public string SceneName {
    get {
        if (scene == null)
        {
            return string.Empty; //maybe or something else
        }
        Debug.Log ("Scene Name : " + scene.name);
        return scene.name;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
In the Editor mode it is never null.
But in the Build it is allways null. 
I don't understand why this is the case.

Comment: Because at runtime things change and they change based on your code. Use the debugger and figure out why.